# D-Link DWA-127 rev B1 drivers

Tags: wireless, usb

Did anybody stumble upon this device before and knows where to start looking for drivers?

lsusb output:

```
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 2001:3d04 D-Link Corp.
```

Was searching the Internet for an hour and didn't find anything.

Thanks,

musli

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add there output of `usb-devices` command

Comment: run `uname -r` in terminal and paste it here.

Comment: also run `lsmod | grep rt`in terminal and paste it in your post creating a section named **EDIT**.

Answer (score 1):

This device is not supported by the kernel driver yet. But it is quite easy to fix it. This dongle has rt2870 chip. But USB VID & PID have not been added to the driver.

This problem can be solved by submitting a bug report to launchpad.

You can do it by running

```
ubuntu-bug linux
```

in terminal. Then follow directions and describe the bug.

Then add link to the bug report to your question here. I will take care of it and make a patch. Then you will be able to test it.